# Kubernetes delete

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

What is the purpose of the `kubectl delete -k <DIR>` command ?

Does it destroy all the resources defined under that specific path?

Thanks

Comment: See [`kubectl delete`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#delete). Specifically it deletes the resources that result from processing the folder as a kustomization directory.

Answer (score 2):

In accordance with the comment posted by @DazWilkin:

**What is the purpose of the kubectl delete -k  command?**

> Delete resources from a directory containing kustomization.yaml - e.g.
> dir/kustomization.yaml

**Does it destroy all the resources defined under that specific path?**

> Specifically, it deletes the resources that result from processing the
> folder as a customization directory.